# What is the complexity of generating all possible sequences with applying if statement in some positions

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have two questions.

First

Imagine we have a list of 3 elements, n=[1,2,3], and we want to generate all possible sequences where the length of the generated list is 7. 
As an example, one possible sequence is m=[1,2,3,1,1,2,3]

The first question is, what is the complexity? exponential or polynomial?

Second

Now we have 7 elements, as previous example [1,2,3,1,1,2,3], and if we say for example, in the first position (left one), we would like to have only number 1, in the second position 1 and 2, in the third, forth, and fifth positions we can have all numbers (1,2,3), in the sixth position 1 and 2, and in the last position only 1, the shape is bell shape.

What is the complexity now?

Comment: Do you have an educated guess on those questions?

Comment: @Yrixmorten the first one is  sequences over a finite domain, and the second one is  sequences over a finite domain with some restriction.

Answer (score 0):

By |x| I mean the length of x, by [x] the largest whole number not bigger than x.

First:

Because the number of distinct possibilities is |n|^|m|, the time complexity will be at least O(|n|^|m|). If you take |n| for constant, and |m| as a variable then the time comlexity will be exponential (with |n| as base). On the other hand if you take |m| as fix and only change |n|, then it becomes polynomial. The space complexity in both case are linear O(|n|+|m|).

Second:

If |m| > 2|n| then O((|m|-2|n|)^|n|*(|n|!)^2), because the two "sides" have  both |n|! possibilities, and the "middle part" can be filled with anything from n.

If |m| <= 2|n| then O([|m|/2]!) if |m| is even and O([|m|/2]!*(m+1)/2) if |m| is an odd number. This is almost the same as above, but without the "middle part".

Space complexity is still O(|m|+|n|).